# Get delta between two times in different formats

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two different time formats

```
    dt0 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).ToLocalTime().AddSeconds(time_0)  //(32-bits)
    dt1 = new DateTime.FromFileTime(time_1)  //(64-bits)
```

I need to find the delta between these two times. Is there a way to do that without converting the `dt0` into 64-bit?

Comment: `DateTime` does not have a format.  I don't understand why you think one is 32 bit and the other is 64.

Comment: Since local time has been mentioned, be certain to understand what should happen when the 2 times span a boundary from DST to Standard Time or vice versa. If the times span a transition rule where the local time moves ahead an hour, should the time differential include that "skipped" hour or not?

Comment: simply try             var delta = dt1.Subtract(dt0);
Format has not impact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert anything - both are `DateTime` objects no matter how you create it. To find the difference:

```
TimeSpan span = dt1 - dt0;
```

Note: [internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,f3e44e197be7d1c9) date is stored as `long` value, which is `ticks` (100-nanosecond intervals) number that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 (well, there is 62 bits for ticks and 2 bits for date kind). Windows file time is also measured in ticks, but it uses different starting point - 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

```
var dt0 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
dt0.Ticks // 621355968000000000 ticks number since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001
dt0.ToFileTime() // 116444664000000000 - I'll use this number later
```

Note that number of ticks from 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 is less than number of ticks from 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001.

```
var dt1 = dt0.ToLocal();
dt1.Ticks // 621356040000000000 depends on time zone, mine is + 2 hours measured in ticks
var dt2 = dt1.AddSeconds(1);
dt2.Ticks // 621356040010000000 you have added 1s = 10000000 ticks
```

In the last sample I have added second represented by integer number, which increased internal 62-bit ticks value by 10000000.

And vice versa - you can use binary data or windows file time to initialize DateTime structure:

```
var dt3 = DateTime.FromFileTime(116444664000000000);
```

That gives `d0` with appropriate time zone offset `1970-01-01T00:00:00+02:00`

Comment: Thank you! Adding to my question: How we take care of Day Light Savings while subtracting. `dt1` accounts for DLS but `dt0` doesn't. So when I subtract them I get an hour of difference. Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: @shreeya when you are converting `dt0` to local time, DLS should be considered automatically. Btw I have added some examples with numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TimeSpan object

```
TimeSpan TimeDelta = new TimeSpan();
TimeDelta  = dt0 - dt1;
```

Comment: Or just make it a one-liner: `TimeSpan TimeDelta = dt0 - dt1;`